# Can I put 28" tires on 27,5" wheel?

Tags: tire, compatibility, size

My bike has 27,5" wheels and the rear tire is due for replacement. Will a 28" tire stay on a 27,5 MTB wheel once inflated to 30+ PSI? This is not a tubeless tire, it has inner tube. Has anyone tried it? I have done enough research to understand that it is not recommended, I am just curious if the tire would stay inside the rim bead seat.
(Reason for even considering this: major price difference)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bead/rim diameter difference between the two sizes is 38mm (622mm - 584mm) or 1 1/2in. So no, there is no way to even fit a 28" tire on a 27.5" rim, as the bead diameter of a 28" tire is even larger than the outer diameter of a 27.5" rim.

The confusion may arise because 27.5", 28" and 29" are considered to be the outer diameter of the wheel - tire included. 27.5" and 29" are coming from the MTB world, that assume large tires (2" or more). 28" is a marketing denomination for road/gravel wheels (with tires narrower than 2"), but the bead diameter for 28" and 29" wheels is the same, the difference in outer diameter is only attributable to a difference in tire size.

Comment: One extra example is some tires marked as 26x1 1/2" (650B) are 584 as well.

Comment: @NoahSutherland do you have an example of a tires marked as 26 & 650B/ISO 584?

Comment: @PaulH Michelin World Tour is one

Comment: @PaulH Sunlite also makes a cheap 26x1-1/2 584 tire: https://www.latitude45.com/product/sunlite-street-tire-650b-232900-1.htm

Comment: @NoahSutherland yeesh. what a mess.

Comment: @PaulH That's just the tip of the iceberg. If you want to really dive into the weirdness that is tire sizing, here's the encyclopedia: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Comment: thank you Renaud for the answer, and thank you PaulH for the link